# SQL Server: pulling and updating local data

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2008, integration

I have two SQL Server 2008 databases called **Anna** and **Bob**.

- **Bob** has to pull and transform data from **Anna** to keep updated
  his tables.
- Ideally **Bob** will be
  always synchronized with **Anna**,
  but some delay would be acceptable.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to regularly update Bob. Use proper SQL Mechanisms so the SSIS task can know which data to touch (only), like change timestamps.

This is a pretty standard Data Warehouse scenario. SSIS was made to support those.

Answer (score -1):

First Anna needs to give Bob her phone number and we'll see where it goes from there.  Delay may be perfectly acceptable if Anna has to wash her hair or something.

Comment: yeh, I too was thinking why not Bob and Mary, then Alice could be the man, er woman-in-the-middle

Comment: I just couldn't resist this one, I don't know what got into me.